# How to validate a field before whole form validation using ValidationEngine

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I'm trying to use ValidationEngine (https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine)
I need to validate one field (for email) before the whole form will be validated:

```
$(document).on("click", "#EmailButton", function(){
    var valid=$("#Email").validationEngine('validate');
    alert(valid);
})
$("#<?=$formName?>").validationEngine({
   promptPosition:'topLeft', 
   scroll: false,
   binded: false,
   onValidationComplete: function(form, status){
if(status==true){                    
           $.ajax({
                type: "POST", ... ... ... }
}
```

So, when I click on `#EmailButton` the `#Email` field should be validated, not whole form.

But when the `#EmailButton` is clicked, the ajax script from `$("#<?=$formName?>").validationEngine({`   is run!

I need this feature because I want to make some changes in the form after the `#Email` field is filled (if email is in Database or not).

How can I validate the `#Email` field before to run the `$("#<?=$formName?>").validationEngine({})` script ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more careful when tagging your questions. jQuery Validate and jQuery Validation Engine are two different things.  Edited.

Comment: No answers? Please, help me! I still not found a solution!

Comment: Begging for help is not constructive.  I've answered hundreds of questions about the jQuery Validate plugin, but unfortunately don't know much about the less popular jQuery Validation Engine.

Comment: Thanks. May be  jQuery Validate plugin is more popular, but the manager requires ValidationEngine! I see  a lot of information about ValidationEngine on this site, there are people which use it. But I not found any useful posts for my problem... I'm still waiting for a help, the problem is not solved... :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

In HTML:

```
<form id="emailForm">
      Email:<input type="email" id="txtEmail" class="validate[required,custom[email],maxSize[30]]"/>
            <input type="button" value="Email Verify" onclick="emailCheck()"/>  
</form>
```

In Jquery:

```
function emailCheck()
{
    if($("#emailForm").validationEngine('validate') == true)
    {
       alert('valid');
    }
    else
    {
       alert('not valid');
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The function returns true when calling the jQuery Validation Engine specific to that field, while calling the same function on the entire form returns false.

Answer (score 1):

The earlier answer is incorrect, if only because the code of the jQuery Validation Engine is also incorrect. The boolean for this code snippet is actually backwards due to a bug in the current version. Try changing "true" to "false" and you should get a working result. Here's the corrected example (assuming the field in question has the ID of 'email'):

```
function validateEmail() {
    var isValid = !$("#email").validationEngine('validate');

    // You may delete the following two lines after confirming that things are working:
    if (isValid) alert('valid');
    else alert('not valid');

    return isValid; // leave this line in -- it will return the result of validation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#Email").validationEngine('validateField',$("#Email"))
```

Comment: Yep, but that is the code that worked for me when I had the same problem so there it is.

Comment: You can read my comment again : "An answer is formed of a sentence explaining a solution". I still don't see a sentence. What does this piece of code do?